# How to force script execution before shutdown or reboot is executed?

Tags: shell, rhel, systemd, shutdown, reboot

I have this service enabled by `systemctl`:

```
[Unit]     
Description=The Oracle Database Service     
After=syslog.target network.target     
Wants=network.target    

[Service]    
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity    
LimitNOFILE=65535     
Type=simple     
KillMode=none     
SendSIGKILL=no     
TimeoutSec=5min 
RemainAfterExit=yes     
TimeoutStopSec=5min     
User=oracle     
Group=oinstall     
ExecStart=/home/oracle/acciones/doc/startup.sh    
ExecStop=/home/oracle/acciones/doc/shutdown.sh

[Install]     
WantedBy=multi-user.target graphical.target
```

The service is working, but after reboot or shutdown the log message indicates that shutdown script was not finished correctly. I am using RHEL7.

Comment: I guess you would have to add `Before=shutdown.target` in `[Unit]` section. Please have a look at `man systemd.special`